# Is there any way to check if I'm under a heading using org-mode API?

Tags: org-mode

To be more specific, suppose I have an org-mode file with the following contents:

```
Foo

* Heading1
Bar

#+begin_src elisp
(message "code")
#+end_src
```

- If my current position is at `Foo`, then I'm not under a heading.
- If my current position is at `Bar`, then I'm under a heading.
- If my current position is at `(message "code")`, then I'm also under a heading.

Is there any way to check it using elisp code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure:

```el
(org-current-level)
```

returns `nil` at `Foo`; it returns 1 (or greater depending on the level) at `Bar` and similar places.

EDIT: in answer to the OP's question about how I found this function: I knew about it already, so chalk it up to experience :-). That is not going to help, so here are some methods to use emacs to help you find such things.

There is an almost universal convention that every package has a unique prefix associated with it; e.g. every function and every variable that Org mode defines starts with the prefix `org-` (there may be exceptions for some things that are meant for internal use only, but they are few and far between: certainly, every function and variable that is meant to be used to customize Org mode and many more besides obey the convention). Org mode also uses a sub-prefix for its major components, e.g Org babel functions are named with the prefix `org-babel-`, export functions use `org-export-` and so on.

The next piece of the puzzle is that Emacs has a *fantastic* help system that every Emacs user should be familiar with. In particular, you can say `C-h f <function-name>` or `C-h v <variable-name>` or `C-h a <command-name>` and get information about the named function, named variable or command name (a function that has been marked `interactive` so you can run it with `M-x <command-name>`). The help system also allows access to the manuals, so `C-h i g(org)` displays the manual in Info and you can navigate and search using Info facilities. That is also indispensable to every Emacs user. And, icing on the cake, it also gives you help about *itself*: `C-h i ?` shows you a page of keys (including the above `f`, `v`, `a`) that let you ask Emacs about some aspect of its operation. Emacs has introspective capabilities that put most other software claiming such to shame - and it has had it for 30 years.

One more piece that I use very frequently is completion: Emacs allows you to specify something partially and provides ways to complete the specification automatically (usually by pressing TAB or some such). There are many completion systems in use but the simplest is the one that is built into Emacs. In the case of interest, I can ask for information on a function whose name I don't know completely, but perhaps I can guess; e.g. in the case above, I know that the function, if it exists, would start with `org-` but I might also guess that the word `level` might appear in its name, so I say `C-h f org--level TAB` and I get 20 possibilities in a completion buffer, which I can scan quickly and see if something jumps out at me: `org-current-level` is there, so I click on it and I get the doc string of the function as if I had typed `C-h f org-current-level` in the first place.

Another possibility is to go to the manual and search the index: `C-h i g (org) i level RET` and then cycle through all the occurrences with `,`. Unfortunately, the function above is not mentioned in the manual (probably because it is not useful to users of Org mode who want to customize it at the top level), so this method does not lead to any results.

So it's a matter of luck to some extent, but knowing the above and biasing your search intelligently can allow you to find things easily and quickly. And the more experience you gain using these methods, the easier and quicker it becomes.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But could you tell me how you found this function?

Comment: I started replying in a comment, but it quickly grew out of all proportion, so I edited the answer instead. Hope the methods are useful to you and others; and if you have additional methods or tricks for searching (googling does not count: it has to be Emacs-related :-) ), feel free to edit the answer and add them.

Comment: Thanks for the searching method, it's really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

That's what `(org-before-first-heading-p)` tells you.